# Is there a way to get the list of all disabled redis commands from redis?

Tags: redis, jedis, lettuce

I am writing a bot (which contains the list of commands to disable), which monitors redis. It disables commands by doing, for eg (rename-command ZADD "")
When I restart my bot, I would want the bot to restart redis, if there is a change in the list of commands to disable, for them to take effect.

Currently I cannot figure out a way, to get the list of disabled commands from redis.

Comment: @Itamar Habar pls help

Comment: That's not my name, but I'll still answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

As @Itamar's answer mentioned, there's no bullt-in way. However, since you are writing a bot, I think you don't mind write some extra code to achieve the goal.

1. Get a full list of commands that's Redis supports from [redis.io](https://redis.io/commands).
2. For each command, send it to Redis
3. If Redis returns an error reply: **(error) ERR unknown command 'XXX'**, that means the `XXX` command has been disabled.

Comment: Yep, that's certainly valid approach (note however latest issue in the redis-doc repo regarding undocumented commands ;))

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't such a way - commands renamed to the empty string are disabled and are not shown by the introspective [`COMMAND` command](https://redis.io/commands/command).

Comment: is there a way to invoke "COMMAND" using jedis ? I dont see it in their api

Answer (score 0):

Jedis is, regrettably, a little retarded in the sense of keeping up with Redis. If the commands isn't exposed by it, I don't think there's much you can do about it. Perhaps use Lettuce?